# How to perform sql group by week and count of users who are created >= the week (Not just in that week)?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Example:

```
| Week | UserId |
| ---- | ------ |
| 0    | A      |
| 0    | B      |
| 0    | C      |
| 1    | D      |
| 1    | E      |
| 1    | F      |
| 2    | G      |
| 3    | H      |
| 3    | I      |
```

Now I want the table like below

```
| Week | Users |
| ---- | ------ |
| 0    | 9      |
| 1    | 6      |
| 2    | 3      |
| 3    | 2      |
```

Now I could use

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    (week_3_users AS 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT User_ID
        FROM users
        WHERE week >= 3
    ),
    week_2_users AS 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT User_ID
        FROM users
        WHERE week >= 2
    ),
    week_1_users AS 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT User_ID
        FROM users
        WHERE week >= 1
    ),
    week_0_users AS 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT User_ID
        FROM users
        WHERE week >= 0
    )
    SELECT 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM week_0_users) AS week_0_count,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM week_1_users JOIN week_0_users USING (User_ID)) AS    week_1_count,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM week_2_users JOIN week_0_users USING (User_ID)) AS week_2_count,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM week_3_users JOIN week_0_users USING (User_ID)) AS week_3_count
)
```

That returns:

```
| week_0_count | week_1_count | week_2_count | week_3_count |
| ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ |
| 9            | 6            | 3            | 2            |
```

But I don't want to repeat that for N number of weeks.

Please suggest of I can do it to get desired output

Comment: please, do not change your question - after it is answered!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cumulative sum:

```
select week, count(*),
       sum(count(*)) over (order by week desc)
from t
group by week
order by week;
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't want to repeat that for N number of weeks.
> Please suggest of I can do it to get desired output

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
execute immediate (
select 'select ' || 
    string_agg('max(if(week =' || week || ',users,null)) week_' || week || '_count', ', ' order by week) || '''
  from (
  select week, sum(count(*)) over (order by week desc) users
  from `project.dataset.users_table` 
  group by week)'''
from (select distinct week from `project.dataset.users_table`)
);
```

If/when applied to sample data from your example - output is

[image]

Comment: Have you tried? isn't this what you asked originally for? :o)